# C# 2.0 function to append particular text in the output file name

Tags: c#

I am having below string and filename, the filename is the output of another function, so it look like below

```
string filename = "maindestination.jpg"; //It can .png, .gif etc depend on the type of file.
```

Then I have got another function which gives the output as below

```
string id = "tcm:123-3455";
```

Now I want to write a function something like below which will do the merging of both the outputted values as below:

```
public static string newFileName(string filename, string strID)
{
string newFileName = "maindestination_tcm:123-3455.jpg"
return newFileName;
}
```

Comment: ':' is invalid at windows file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string GetFileNameWithId(string fileName, string strId) {
    return string.Format(
            "{0}_{1}{2}",
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
            strId,
            Path.GetExtension(fileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods in the Path class, in the System.IO namespace:

```
string newFileName=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)+"_"+strID+Path.GetExtension(filename);
```

By the way, this will work on any version of the .NET Framework, not just in C# 2.0.

Comment: Sorry no need of "'" as this was added by mistake